# Convergence or divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}(2+(-1)^n)/n$?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, summation, divergent-series

Is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}{(2+(-1)^n)\over n}$$ convergent or divergent?

Comment: Hint: break it up into two series. One is easily shown to be convergent while the other is easily shown to be divergent.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal no, it diverges.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM: You are right!  I was checking that!

Answer (score 1):

Here I provide an answer using basic convergence tests as well as one without such tests

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}{(2+(-1)^n)\over n}$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{2}{n} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{2}{n} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$$
The first series is clearly convergent by the alternating series test, though the latter is the harmonic series, which is divergent. As a result, the original sum must diverge.

As an addendum, the first sum can be shown to be $\log(4)$ using Taylor Series, which is clearly convergent. Let's do so.

We know that the definition of the Taylor Series centered at $x=a$ is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)(x-a)^n}{n!}$. Let's use the fairly well known fact that
$$\frac{1}{1-x} = 1+x+x^2+x^3\cdots$$
We then know that
$$-\log(1-x) = \int_0^x \frac{1}{1-t}$$
And we combine these facts (assuming a lot of little things in the process) yielding
$$-\log(1-x) = -\int_0^x \frac{1}{1-t} dt = \int_0^x \left(1+t+t^2+t^3\cdots\right) dt = x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + \cdots = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k}$$
When we evaluate this series at $x=-1$ we get
$$-\log(2) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k}$$
Multiplying by $-2$ we get that
$$2\log(2) = -2\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k} = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}\frac{2}{k}$$
Thus we have the series we desired.

If you want to show that the latter sum diverges without using tests then observe that the harmonic series is the following:
$$\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{11} + \frac{1}{12} + \cdots$$
The harmonic series will thus be greater than the following series at any finite point, as each term is larger
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{16}+\cdots$$
Notice, however, that the fractions form blocks, namely
$$\frac{1}{2}(1)+\frac{1}{4}(2)+\frac{1}{8}(4) + \frac{1}{16}(8) +\cdots$$
We can rewrite this as
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} +\cdots$$
And the above series clearly diverges. Since the harmonic series is greater at each finite point, the harmonic series must likewise diverge.

Comment: Some caution is needed before you write $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}{(2+(-1)^n)\over n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{2}{n} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. It would be notationally more correct to work with partial sums at that point.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM This is true, however I felt that the answer would be less intuitive and thus harder to understand... ForgotALot posted an answer using that logic, so I figured that would suffice should the OP take that route. There is definitely still room for improvement, so feel free to post a more carefully crafted answer!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:  the sum of an even $n=2k$ term and the following term is $$-{3\over n}+{1\over n+1}=-{2n+3\over n(n+1)}=-{4k+3\over 2k(2k+1)}.$$
That looks divergent to me based on $\sum 1/k$ diverging.